# Pyparsing: space as a valid token

Tags: python, pyparsing

I'm using pyparser to process the output of a hex-to-text converter.  It prints out 16 characters per line, separated by spaces.  If the hex value is an ASCII-printable character, that character is printed, otherwise the converter outputs a period (.)

Mostly the output looks like this:

```
. a . v a l i d . s t r i n g .
. a n o t h e r . s t r i n g .
. e t c . . . . . . . . . . . .
```

My pyparsing code to describe this line is:

```
dump_line = 16 * Word(printables, exact=1)
```

This works fine, until the hex-to-text converter hits a hex value of 0x20, which causes it to output a space.

```
l i n e . w . a .   s p a c e .
```

In that case, pyparsing ignores the outputted space and takes up characters from the following line to make the "quota" of 16 characters.

Can someone please suggest how I can tell pyparsing to expect 16 characters, each separated by a space, where a space can also be a valid character?

Thanks in advance.
J

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since this has significant whitespace, you'll need to tell your character expression to leave leading whitespace alone.  See how this is done below in the definition of dumpchar:

```
hexdump = """\
. a . v a l i d . s t r i n g . 
. a n o t h e r . s t r i n g . 
. e t c . . . . . . . . . . . . 
l i n e . w . a .   s p a c e . 
. e t c . . . . . . . . . . . . 
"""

from pyparsing import oneOf, printables, delimitedList, White, LineEnd

# expression for a single char or space
dumpchar = oneOf(list(printables)+[' ']).leaveWhitespace()

# convert '.'s to something else, if you like; in this example, '_'
dumpchar.setParseAction(lambda t:'_' if t[0]=='.' else None)

# expression for a whole line of dump chars - intervening spaces will
# be discarded by delimitedList
dumpline = delimitedList(dumpchar, delim=White(' ',exact=1)) + LineEnd().suppress()

# if you want the intervening spaces, use this form instead
#dumpline = delimitedList(dumpchar, delim=White(' ',exact=1), combine=True) + LineEnd().suppress()

# read dumped lines from hexdump
for t in dumpline.searchString(hexdump):
    print ''.join(t)
```

Prints:

```
_a_valid_string_
_another_string_
_etc____________
line_w_a_ space_
_etc____________
```

Comment: Hi Paul.  Thanks for the fast response.  I'm getting "pyparsing.ParseException: Expected end of line" unless I remove the LineEnd().  Does LineEnd() recognize Linux's linefeeds (0x0A only) as Line Ends?

Comment: Are you running this code as posted, are are you parsing each line separately?  `LineEnd()` should be looking for a `\n`, which I'm assuming Python would do the right os-dependent thing for your system.  I just did a crude test in the interpreter on both Windows and Linux: `LineEnd() == '\n'` and both returned True.

Comment: Thanks Paul!  This solution works great.  The LineEnd() issue turned out to be the result of my using parseString() instead of a FOR loop calling searchString().  It's working now.  Thanks again for the help and quick responses!

Answer (score 1):

Consider using another way to remove the spaces

```
>>> s=". a . v a l i d . s t r i n g ."
>>> s=s[::2]
>>> s
'.a.valid.string.'
```

Comment: Yeah, pyparsing seems like major overkill for this.

Comment: The problem stated represents a small part of a much larger report that needs the "oomph" of pyparsing to parse.  Otherwise, yeah, this would be a much more direct solution.

Comment: Could you reasonably have PyParsing consider the whole ASCII dump one token, and then apply this transformation to the entire dump, then?

Comment: Yes, if the entire report was in this format.  The ASCII dump represents just one small section of a much larger report with many varied text fields, formats and layouts.  If the entire report was in the format I describe in the problem, this would be a much more concise solution and pyparsing would be overkill.

Comment: Is the field in question clearly delimited? If so, does pyparsing let you transform the text of this field as it is processed by using a lambda that applies this answer's slice idea?